# Codificación de utf8 en archivos Json de NetBeans

Tags: java, json, netbeans, codificación

Tengo una componente [angular](/questions/tagged/angular) para traducir una archivo `.JSON`, mi problema esta al escapar los caracteres especiales como: acentos y eñes. En [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) hago uso de los acentos y eñes y en la página web muestra correctamente, pero cuando abro el archivo json desde el terminal (consola) o de cualquier otro editor de texto, no Escapa en su equivalente UTF-8. Toda mi aplicación esta codificada en UTF8.

PREGUNTA: Cómo hago para escapar los caracteres especiales en los archivos Json? Quiero que escape caracteres `\uXXXX`. Tal cual los [archivo-de-propiedades](/questions/tagged/archivo-de-propiedades) `.properties` de java.

Aqui cito la codificacion de .properties :

> En general,
>   * .properties siempre usan la codificación ISO-8859-1 más \ uXXXX escapes. (Los caracteres internacionales se mostrarán de forma nativa
>   en el editor pero se almacenarán como un escape en el disco.) Porfavor
>   alguien responda

Answer (score 0):

prueba insertando esto , puede que te sirva:

```
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8"})
```

Comment: eso en mi componente angular ? o en donde lo inserto?Gracias por responder

Comment: @danilo es parte de [tag:Java-ee], https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/Produces.html de un api llamado [tag:JAX-RS] que sirve para crear servicios rest usando solamente anotaciones

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que tienes son archivos, te recomiendo usar la herramienta [native2ascii](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/native2ascii.html) que vine con tu JDK, se usa dela siguiente manera

```
native2ascii -encoding utf8 entrada.txt salida.txt
```