# estoy utilizando codigo ascii para algunos caracteres especiales, pero me salta un error por estos mismos ¿Qué hago?

Tags: java, codificación, windows-1252

aclaro algo cuando intento compilar el código es que me salta el error, a mi me enseñaron que desde un CMD para compilar en java en con java c (nombre del proyecto).java

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

lo que quiero imprimir es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Debes [edit] tu pregunta y el código colocarlo como texto

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Asegúrate de que la codificación del archivo sea UTF-8. Por cierto, alguien tuvo [el mismo problema](https://stackoverflow.com/q/464874/13419694).

Comment: Tienes dos opciones, una guardar tu archivo en la codificación windows-1252 o escapar los caracteres especiales usando unicode como en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/51169/codificaci%c3%b3n-de-utf8-en-archivos-json-de-netbeans/287181#287181